# Layouts and Subclasses

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, subclass

(I am new to Android and Java so please forgive any incorrect phrasing and terminology. I try my best to make sense)

I created a `Layout` called `game_activity.xml`. Then in class `Game`, in `onCreate`, I set the content view to `game_activity`:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);
    }

     //...code
     //...code
}
```

I also created a `Subclass` `Container` which extends `LinearLayout`:

```
private class Container extends LinearLayout {

    public Container(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    //...code
    //...code
}
```

In `game_activity.xml`, there is a `LinearLayout` called `mainLayout`. I want `mainLayout` to be part of `Container` but I don't know how to implement it correctly.
I tried something like this:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout mainLayout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

            mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            mainLayout = new Container(getApplicationContext());
    }

    private class Container extends LinearLayout {

        public Container(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

     //... code
     //... code
    }
}
```

But this method does not work. How do I make `mainLayout` part of `Container` class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `game_activity.xml`, instead of having `<LinearLayout></LinearLayout>` tags, you would want `<com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.Container></com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.Container>` tags instead. You can find your package name in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Then to get a reference to your `Container` in `Game`, the code would look something like:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    private Container mainLayout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

            mainLayout = (Container) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    }

    private static class Container extends LinearLayout {

        public Container(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

     //... code
     //... code
    }
}
```

Side note, you should probably think about moving `Container` to its own file. Otherwise, you have to make it a `static` class. Also, when getting references to objects laid out in xml, you don't have to construct them yourself, as Android will construct instances as part of the layout inflation process.

EDIT: Sorry, misread the question. To have a `LinearLayout` within your `Container` class, your `game_activity.xml` should read something like:

```
<com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.Container 
    attributes...>

    <LinearLayout
        attributes...>

        <SomeRandomView
            attributes... />

    </LinearLayout>
</com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.Container>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed and specific answer. I think this is exactly what I need. I am going to test this out now and see if it works.

Comment: In the xml I get this notification: Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- com.example.hello_world.Container (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
Do you know why?

Comment: Is your `Container` class in its own file, named `Container.java`? I would recommend using an IDE such as AndroidStudio, which will try to guess which custom class you're trying to add, as typing the full package name and path gets tiresome quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Add LinearLayouts within the already existing LinearLayouts. 
So, as your question speaks, you need the mainLayout LinearLayout to be a Part of the Container (Subclass of Linear Layout class).

You can simply add the Container Layout to your Xml file and then add the MainLayout Linear Layout into your Container Layout programatically.

Then for accessing purpose of the internal LinearLayout within the Container Class you can simply put some Tag on the added mainLayout object and access it inside the Container class by traversing the Children and finding the Child Layout with the associated Tag.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How would I add the Container Layout to my xml?